# コンパイルはできるので、どこがおかしいかわからない。

Tags: c

関数diffを2つの値xとyの差（大きい方から小さい方を引いた値）を返す関数とし、それを以下のようにプログラムしたのですが、どんな数字を入れても差は0という結果しか出力されませんでした。

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* 2つの値 x, y の差(大きい方から小さい方を引いた値)を返す関数 */
int diff(int x, int y)
{
    int diff;

    if (x>=y) {
        diff=x-y;
    }
    else if(y>x){
        y-x;
    }

    return diff;
}

int main(void)
{
    int x, y;

    printf("整数 x を入力してください：");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("整数 y を入力してください：");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    printf("整数 x と y の差は %d です．\n", diff(x,y));

    return 0;
}
```

**実行結果**

```
$ ./a.out
整数 x を入力してください：13
整数 y を入力してください：34
整数 x と y の差は 0 です．
```

上記のような実行結果しか出力されなかったのですが、自分では欠損点が見つからなかったので聞いている次第です。
ご回答よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

y>xの場合にdiffに差を格納していないからですね。
(x>=yの場合は修正前のプログラムでも正しい結果が出ています。)

```
        if (x>=y) {
                diff=x-y;
        }
        else if(y>x){
                /* y-x; diffに格納していない。 */
                diff=y-x; /* diffへ格納するように修正 */
        }
```

Comment: diffを格納したところ、コンパイルができ、きちんとした結果が出ました。ご回答有難うございます。

Comment: 問題は関数diffの返り値を、diffに格納していなかった事ですね。
コンパイルができるというのは、そのコードがプログラミング言語の文法に反していないという事を意味しているだけで、コードがそれを書いた人の意図どおりに動くということではないです。
そういう視点で自分のコードを見直せるようになると、プログラムのバグを見抜けるようになりますよ。がんばれ！

Answer (score 3):

既に解決済みですので参考までに。

例えば gcc ではスイッチオプションに `-Wunused-value` を追加すると(`-Wall` でも可)、以下の様に warning message を表示してくれます。

```
$ gcc -std=c18 -Wunused-value -g diff_values.c
diff_values.c: In function ‘diff’:
diff_values.c:12:6: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
   12 |     y-x;
      |     ~^~
```

ちなみに、三項演算子(`ternary operator`)を使うと以下の様にも書くことができます(macro でもよいかもしれません)。

```c
int diff(int x, int y)
{
  return (x>y) ? (x-y) : (y-x);
}
```